# How do I map a resource the root of an application in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, resources, controller, root

In routes.rb, I'm using `resources` to declare all common routes for a controller:

```
resources :photos
```

This creates URLs which look like this:

```
http://example.com/photos
http://example.com/photos/new
...
```

How do I remove `photos` from the URLs?  That is, how do I map this controller to the root of the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can route a resourceful controller to the root by adding the `path` option:

```
resources :photos, :path => "/"
```

And, of course, this can still be extended in the usual way;

```
resources :photos, :path => "/" do
  member do
    get 'view_original_size'
  end
end
```

For more information, see [Module
ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper::Resources > resources > Supported options](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html) in the API documentation.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this with us.  Also, thanks for doing it using our question/answer format.